# moveToLocation and open Marker-Popup automatically

Tags: leaflet, javascript, popup, markers

For reference: I use `L.Control.Search` to search for my Marker.

It's this Plugin: https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/master/examples/multiple-layers.html

And this is the working search function: https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/multiple-layers.html

My problem: 
Now, I want the popup of the marker I searched for to open automatically without me clicking. I butchered the code from a polygon layer, but can I make it work for only markers? I don't get any errors but don't get a popup either.

```
       var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
            layer: myLayer,
            propertyName: 'name',
            collapsed: false,
            container: 'findbox',
            textPlaceholder: 'Search',
            marker: false,
            initial: false,
            buildTip: function (text, val) {
                var type = val.layer.feature.properties.iconcategory;
                return '<a href="#" class="' + type + '">' + text + '<b>' + type + '</b></a>';
            },

          moveToLocation: function (latlng, title, map, feature) {
                var zoom = 16;
                map.setView(latlng, zoom);
            }, 
        });

        searchControl.on('search:locationfound', function(e, feature) {

    if(e.layer._popup)
        e.layer.openPopup("test");

}).on('search:collapsed', function(e) {

    filterLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) { 
        filterLayer.resetStyle(layer);
    }); 
});

        map.addControl(searchControl);
```

This is a glimpse of the code I used for the popups.

```
onEachFeature: function forEachFeature(feature, layer) {

            var popups = "Name <b>" +
                feature.properties.name + "</b>;

            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popups) {
                popups += feature.properties.popups;
            } layer.bindPopup(popups);

        },
```

Comment: Code above looks OK (except missing ending quote in `feature.properties.name + "</b>;`, but you should get error for that), so it's impossible to say what's wrong without possibility to test complete code. What do you see if you inspect `e.layer._popup` in the browser debugger?

Comment: There was a link to your full code in your comment that now dissappeared? Do you still need/expect help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple thing that's wrong can be found in code above. Popup that is attached to layer can be opened only with `.openPopup()` or `.openPopup(latLng)` calls (see https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup). Both calls open existing popup content , so `e.layer.openPopup("test")` call does not work.

To change content of the layer popup on the fly when popup already exists, `.setPopupContent()` method has to be used, for example:

```
layer.setPopupContent(feature.properties.someProperty);
layer.openPopup();
```

Finding the other thing that is preventing popup display was quite tricky and possible only because the full code was available. In the full code there is a part that allows for different parts of GeoJSON layers to be filtered through dynamic select by clicking on checkboxes:

```
function updatecheckboxen() {
  checkboxen = {
    lines: [],
    escalators: [],
    wheelchairs: [],
    elevators: [],
    linien: [],
    aufzuge: [],
    rollstuhle: [],
    rolltreppen: [],
    untere30: [],
    uebere30: []
  }

  for (let input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
    if (input.checked) {
      switch (input.className) {
        case 'line': checkboxen.lines.push(input.value); break
        case 'escalator': checkboxen.escalators.push(input.value); break
        case 'wheelchair': checkboxen.wheelchairs.push(input.value); break
        case 'elevator': checkboxen.elevators.push(input.value); break

        case 'linie': checkboxen.linien.push(input.value); break
        case 'aufzug': checkboxen.aufzuge.push(input.value); break
        case 'rollstuhl': checkboxen.rollstuhle.push(input.value); break
        case 'rolltreppe': checkboxen.rolltreppen.push(input.value); break
        case 'unter30': checkboxen.untere30.push(input.value); break
        case 'ueber30': checkboxen.uebere30.push(input.value); break
      }
    }
  }
}

for (let input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
  input.onchange = (e) => {
    filterLayer.clearLayers()
    updatecheckboxen()
    filterLayer.addData([ubahn, tram])
  }
}
```

This code by itself is OK, the only problem is query selector `.querySelectorAll('input')`, which besides checkbox inputs selects also search condition input field. As a result, when search condition is entered, it triggers `input.onchange` processing function. Event is triggered after location is found and popup displayed, and as a consequence overlay is loaded again and as a consequence popup is closed. This happens so quickly that it appears popup was not opened at all.

Solution is to use different query selector that select only checkbox input fields:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[type = checkbox]')
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. I tried `layer.setContent(feature.properties.name); layer.openPopup();` but it can't read the setContent(). _Cannot read property 'setContent' of undefined._ I tried `e.layer.bindPopup('test').openPopup()  console.log(e.latlng)` and at least it's opening a popup. But as soon as I wanna use the setContent() it's not working anymore.

Comment: Ups, my mistake, it should be `layer.setPopupContent(…)`. Answer edited and corrected.

Comment: No, setContent() is right. https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#popup-setcontent (And even with setPopupContent, I get the same error.)

Comment: Method `.setContent()` is for popup object, `.setPopupContent()` is for layer object. In your case you are setting popup content of a layer. If you want to use `.setContent`, then it should be `layer.getPopup().setContent(…)`

Comment: Tried ` layer.getPopup().setContent('test')  layer.openPopup();` and `layer.setPopupContent('test') layer.openPopup();`. In both cases I get _Cannot read property 'getPopup' of undefined_ and _Cannot read property 'setPopupContent' of undefined_. When I use `e.layer.getPopup().setContent('test'); e.layer.openPopup();` it's opening the Popup, but `feature.properties.name` in `setContent()` (and the other case with `setPopupContent()`) isn't working.

Comment: These methods work only if popup is already defined for the layer. If not, you have to use `.bindPopup()` method.

Comment: Somehow I couldn't get your suggestions to work. Using `console.log(e.latlng); e.layer.openPopup();` now and it opens my popups without me having to define something new.

Comment: But changing `input` was necessary. Thank you.